# Input Box Filter Macro

Tags: excel, search, filter, vba

I have searched for a solution to the following issue and tried to solve it myself but unfortunately my limited knowledge of macros has led me to a dead end!

The following is a code from my current macro that I am trying to setup to make a repetitive role in work easier.

I would like to filter 2 separate reports on separate tabs in the same workbook, copy and paste the results to new tabs with a paste values based on an input box to be populated with search criteria. if this makes sense.

The macro works apart from the fact it has saved the search criteria as a definite number in bedded into the macro instead of using the cell reference I tried to link it to being "B2" in this case on a tab called "Report Input"

Basically - Copy values in "B2" from Tab 1 "Report Input", regardless of the number (not necessarily 560623), look at tab 2 "Invoice Backup" and filter based on cell "b2" from tab 1...copy and paste values to tab 3....then repeat the process with another report...

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    Sub ReportFilter()
    '
    ' ReportFilter Macro
    '

    '
        Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("TDR Backup").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$56298").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "560623"
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("TDR").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Report Input").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Invoice Backup").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Sheets("Report Input").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Invoice Backup").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$340548").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "560623"
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Invoice").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-48
    Range("E546").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("E67").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Sheets("TDR").Select
    Range("D39").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-66
    Sheets("TDR Backup").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Sheets("Invoice Backup").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("G8").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `"560623"` at the end of the 2 Autofilter lines to

`Sheets("Report Input").range("B2")`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly and has saved me so much time!